# In a function, is there a way to get a list of all the paramters the user explicitly used?

Tags: autohotkey

This is something I do all the time in PowerShell. The object `$PsBoundParameters` contains an array of all the parameters that a user explicitly invoked, parameters with default values are not included.

In AHK if I have a function with the following parameters  and I were to invoke it as `MyCar("Red",, 4)`, inside the function how do I then get the parameters that were used?

```
MyCar(Color, TyreCount, SeatCount, Plate := 1975){
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Color := "Red"
SeatCount := 4

MsgBox, % MyCar(Color, TyreCount, SeatCount)

MyCar(Color, TyreCount, SeatCount, Plate := 1975){
    return "Color = " color  "`nTyreCount = " TyreCount "`nSeatCount = " SeatCount "`nPlate = " Plate 
}
```

or

```
MsgBox, % MyCar("Red","", "4")

MyCar(Color, TyreCount, SeatCount, Plate := 1975){
    return "Color = " color  "`nTyreCount = " TyreCount "`nSeatCount = " SeatCount "`nPlate = " Plate 
}
```

if I understand your question right.

Comment: Not exactly, the object I am looking for is meant for use within the function, unless your `Return` line is for illustration puropose only. [This](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Func.htm#IsVariadic) page from the docs is what I was looking for. Cheers!